# Why pull request doesn't trigger with Jenkins and Github?

Tags: git, jenkins

I want to trigger the build in Jenkins only when the pull request is approved and merge into the master.

I did as [say in this article](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-integrate-your-github-repository-to-your-jenkins-project) .

But the pr doesn't trigger the Jenkins job.

Here I defined a webhook:

[image]

And setup Jenkins Job:

[image]

In my vscode I create a branch, did the change and commit and push and publish.

[image]

After that I create a pull request to merge into the master.

[image]

I click on the merge button and it merged into the master.

[image]

But the job build wasn't trigger. nothing happens in Jenkins.

- If I add "push" and push to the repo, it trigger the Jenkins build- but I want to do it in just PR.

Any ideas what is wrong here? what I missing here? how to make it work?

Comment: You're only building master, not v9-brance

Comment: what you mean? I merge the branch into the master, and I want to trigger the build. this is what I did, no?

Comment: I just want to merge the branch and Jenkins will trigger the build after, how do I change my configuration to achieve this goal?

Comment: Don't you want to build the PR *before* merging, to test it?

Comment: sound reasonable. but using Jenkins I also do the deploy right? (maybe in a different job?)

Comment: When I think about it, my deploy.sh will build the app. and if it failed it stop the process. if it success then deploy the master.. is it not the right way to handle Jenkins process?

Answer (score 0):

I think that only after you merge to master, your job will be triggered using GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling. The documentation says:

> If Jenkins will receive PUSH GitHub hook from repo defined in Git SCM section it will trigger Git SCM polling logic. So polling logic in fact belongs to Git SCM.

So the pull request won't trigger the job, it's the push (merge to master) which will do this.